# New MBP suddenly can't find any more Wi-Fi networks

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi

I've got a 2016 MacBook Pro for about a month now, and everything has worked very smoothly until today.
Suddenly I couldn't detect any Wi-Fi networks in my area anymore. (including neighbour's Wi-Fi, hotspots, etc...).

This is very strange, since all my other devices still have a perfect Wi-Fi connection. I searched solutions on the internet and I've tried many things, but no success.

- I tried restarting my MBP multiple times
- Setting up portable hotspot on my phone to see if my MBP would find it. It didn't.
- Resetting PRAM didn't help.
- Removing all my default networks didn't do anything.
- **Restarting in Safe Boot** was the only thing that did do something. Strangely enough, I was able find all my Wi-Fi networks while I was in Safe Boot, but when I rebooted back to normal, the Wi-Fi was gone once again.

Does somebody have an idea of what might be going on?
Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**: After a couple of hours the problem seemed to have solved itself after I restarted once again in safe boot and then restarted back to normal. My Wi-Fi works again (for now) but I'm not sure if it will stay that way. I'll update this again if it would break again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a week of trying to figure out what was going on, I finally found out the reason. Apparently there was an **IP conflict** with my TV, so when the TV was turned on, I couldn't connect to internet.

I solved the problem by giving my MBP a **different IP address** so there weren't any conflicts anymore. 
It's working perfect right now.

Answer (score 4):

Did you try to delete those network plist file?

Doing this you "Reset" the Wi-Fi:

1. Close your Wi-Fi from Macbook
2. From toolbar select -> Go -> Go To Folder
3. Paste this address `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/`
4. Locate and delete these files

   - `com.apple.airport.preferences.plist`
   - `com.apple.network.identification.plist`
   - `com.apple.wifi.message-tracer.plist`
   - `NetworkInterfaces.plist`
   - `preferences.plist`
5. Now restart your Macbook
6. Open your Wi-Fi and test again

Comment: Thank you for the response! I have indeed not deleted those files, but I won't be able to tell if it would work, because somehow, after a couple of hours the problem suddenly solved itself after a couple of reboots. I don't know if it will to happen again, but if it does I'll certainly try your solution and let you know if it works ;)

Comment: Ok so, it happened again, and I think I found out why. There was an IP conflict between my MBP and my TV, which meant that my MBP couldn't connect to the internet while the TV was on. Still thank you for your answer!

Comment: Always here to help, did you find how to solve this problem?

Comment: Yes, I managed to give my MBP it's own IP address and now there aren't any conflicts anymore. It's working fine now.

Comment: Happy to know that! Just to inform you if you don't know there is an option `Renew DHCP Lease` in `Network Preferences -> Advanced...` that might help you in the future